# OpenSSH suddenly went into "hash mismatch"?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

The openssh server was running normally in my vps and today it suddenly breaks. Any attempt that I connect from my PC or other places to it results in the following error:

```
hash mismatch
ssh_rsa_verify: signature incorrect
key_verify failed for server_host_key
```

And I connect from the vps to anywhere else results in the same error. However `ssh localhost` from the vps is okay.

I tried `rm -rf /etc/ssh/*` and re-install openssh-server, but that didn't help.

The os is ubuntu 10.04 and all packages are up to date. Could you help me with the strange error?

Comment: so, what was the underlying problem? seems like you've solved it, since there's an accepted answer

Comment: No, it seems to be my VPS provider's fault, and he reset the whole VPS before I could make further tests =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ssh -v or ssh -v -v or even ssh -v -v -v (Each increases verbosity mode). With this "debugging mode" maybe it will be easier to get a handle on the problem.

This will then give you more information so that you can actually locate the problem and fix it.